# dd output explanation

Tags: command-line, dd

could anyone explain what all the output of dd means:

```
58054+190 records in
58054+190 records out
1951551168512 bytes (2,0 TB, 1,8 TiB) copied, 19260,5 s, 101 MB/s
```

I'm especially interested into the meaning of the two human-readable size values in the last line. What is the difference between those two (I haven't been able to find anything about this on the internet)?

Comment: Base 10 vs. Base 2. This is GB & GiB, but same description. TB is 1000GB or TiB is 1024 GiB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte
It's the difference between gigabytes (GB) and gibibytes (GiB). One gigabyte = 1000 x 1000 x 1000 bytes (base 10). One gibibyte = 1024 x 1024 x 1024 bytes (base 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base 10 vs. Base 2.

This is GB & GiB, but same description base difference.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

It's the difference between gigabytes (GB) and gibibytes (GiB). 
One gigabyte = 1000 x 1000 x 1000 bytes (base 10). 
One gibibyte = 1024 x 1024 x 1024 bytes (base 2).

Similarly:
 TB is 1000GB or TiB is 1024 GiB.